Page not loading styling for Amp-story-player when reloaded

The main issue is for the first time the amp-story-player runs the inside 'a' tag and will present
the story as expected , But when we refresh the page or send the link via share it would show me
blank page , (It is important to note here that although no content can be seen (The html is loaded > but not css) , but if i put other tags like Hello before amp story then it will be > shown)


so we used storyCard -> useClick on in it then -> [..slug] -> storyPlayer
[..slug] and storyPlayer.tsx is given .


// this is [[...slug]].tsx


import * as React from 'react';
import { useEffect ,useState,useRef,} from 'react';

import { useRouter } from 'next/router';
import { GetServerSideProps, InferGetServerSidePropsType } from "next/types";
import StoryPlayer from 'app/components/StoryPlayer';

import {
  storyBoardSearch,
} from "app/utils/_meilisearch";



const slugify = require('slugify')





const RealStory =  ({
  stories: st,
  
}: InferGetServerSidePropsType<typeof getServerSideProps>) => {
  
  
  
  
  const setStory = () =>{

    
    const query = router.query;
    if(router && router.query && router.query.slug){
    const uuid = (router?.query?.slug[1]);

    console.log(uuid);
    
    // console.log(st[0],uuid);
    
    setMeiliStories(st[0]);
    story = st[0].find(({ board_uuid }) => board_uuid === uuid);

    console.log(story);
    
    router.query['story'] = story.story_link;
    router.query['id'] = (story.id);



    
   }
    
  }
  const [meiliStories,setMeiliStories] = useState([]);
  const router = useRouter();
  const storyRef = useRef(null);
  let story:any= {};

  useEffect(()=>{
    setStory();
  },[]);
  

  

  
  
 
  return (
    
     <>
      {router.query.story && router.query.id &&
      <StoryPlayer id ={router.query.id as string} url={router.query.story as string} meiliStories={meiliStories} />}
        
      </>
  );
}

export default RealStory;




export const getServerSideProps: GetServerSideProps<ServerProps> = async (
  request
) => {
   


  const categories = await storyBoardSearch.getDocuments({ limit: 10 });

  if (categories) {
    return {
      props: {
        stories: [
          categories.results
        ],
      },
    };
  } 
};

 export interface ServerProps {
  stories: any[];
}



// this is storyPlayer.tsx
import { storyBoardSearch } from "app/utils/_meilisearch";
import { on } from "events";
import MeiliSearch from "meilisearch";
import { GetServerSideProps } from "next";
import { useRouter } from "next/router";
import { useEffect, useRef, useState } from "react";

const slugify = require('slugify');
//consider id (5) as 1 so id-5+1 = id-4

export default function StoryPlayer({
  url,
  meiliStories,
  id,
}: {
  url: string;
  meiliStories: any[];
  id: string;
}) {
  const storyRef = useRef(null);
  const router = useRouter();
  let offset = +id - 4;
  let limit = 20;
  let url2;
  let index;
  // let filteredStories = [];
  // console.log("meiliStories : ", meiliStories);

  const [storyLink,setStoryLink] =  useState<String>("");
  let Id = Number(id)-5;


  

  


  
 
  useEffect(() => {
    if (storyRef.current) {

      storyRef.current.addEventListener("amp-story-player-close", (d) => {
        
        const query = { ...router.query };
        delete query.story;
        delete query.id;
        router.push('/');
        
      });
      
      storyRef.current.addEventListener("navigation", (event) => {
        console.log("navigation fired!", event);
        const query = router.query;

        Id = Id+1;
        const story = meiliStories[Id];

        
        
        if(story){
          const {id,story_link,story_title,board_uuid:uuid} = story;

          router.query['story'] = story_link;
          router.query['id'] = (id);
          

          console.log(story_title);
          let newSlug = story_title;
          if(newSlug.length>20){
            newSlug = newSlug.substring(0,21);
           }
            newSlug = slugify(newSlug,'-');
            router.push(
              { query, pathname: router.pathname },
               `/board/${newSlug}/${uuid}`
            );
        }
        
        
      });
    }
    
    console.log(url,"entered");


  }, [router.query,storyLink, storyRef.current, router.query.story]);
  
  
  
 
  const ampStoryPlayerJson = {
    behavior: {
      pageScroll: false,
      on: "end",
      action: "fetch",
      // endpoint: `/api/feeds?limit=20&offset=${offset}&search=''`,
    },
    controls: [
      {
        name: "close",
        position: "end",
      },
      {
        name: "skip-to-next",
      },
    ],
  };

  

  return (
    <>

    {router.query && router.query.story && router.query.id &&
      <div className="w-screen h-screen fixed top-0 left-0 z-50 anim-scale_ backdrop-blur-lg" onLoad={()=>console.log("chlau")}>
          

          <div>Hello</div>
            <amp-story-player
              id="my-plyer"
              on="load:myAction"
              className="h-full w-full relative" 
              // // layout="fixed-height"
              layout="responsive"
              data-locale="en"
              ref={storyRef}
              height='100vh'

            >
                  <script type="application/json">
                    {JSON.stringify(ampStoryPlayerJson)}
                  </script>
                      
          {meiliStories &&
            meiliStories.slice(Number(id)-5).map((story, i) => {
              
             
              const {story_link} = story;
              return (
                      <a href={story_link} key={i + 1}></a>);
                      
                    })
                  }
            </amp-story-player>

      </div>}
        

       
    </>
  );
}


